# asp.net web api 2 and jquery post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I'm learning asp.net web mvc 5 / asp.net web api 2. Now, I've created a default web api 2 project (with bootstrap template). I also enabled Cors via these steps: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors

When I run the project and try to call the api via Fiddler Web Debugger, it all works fine. This is the raw request I sent:

POST http:///mywebapi/Token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencode
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: 
Content-Length: 71

grant_type=password&userName=me@mymail.com&Password=mypwd01

But now I try to call the api via a jQuery ajax call, and now I got stuck.
This is what I have so far:

```
function sendRequest() {
            //var method = $('#method').val();
            var email = 'me@mymail.com';
            var pwd = 'mypwd01!';

            $.ajax({
                //crossDomain: true,
                type: 'post',
                url: serviceUrl,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                data: 'grant_type=password&userName='+ email + '&Password=' + pwd,
                xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
            }).done(function (data) {
                $('#value1').text(data);
            }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#value1').text(jqXHR.responseText || textStatus);
            });
        }
```

Now when I run my page, I get the error 400, Bad request (on my local machine). When I run the same page on the server, I get a 200 response. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to create a connection. I have some doubts about if this is the correct way, so any advise is welcome. My final goal is to create a phonegap / ionic app that can do authorised calls to the server. For now, this is what I did:

On the server, besides enabling cors (see my initial question above) I've also added the following lines in the webconfig:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol> 
</system.webServer>
```

I used the * because of mobile phones need to make calls to the server (phonegap/ionic).

Now, I've changed my client code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    //crossDomain: true,
    type: "POST",
    url: serviceUrl,
    //processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    data: 'grant_type=password&userName=' + email + '&Password='+ pwd,
}).done(function (data) {
    $('#value1').text(JSON.stringify(data));
}).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('#value1').text(jqXHR.responseText || textStatus);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as below

```
function sendRequest() {
        //var method = $('#method').val();
        var email = 'me@mymail.com';
        var pwd = 'mypwd01!';

        $.ajax({
            //crossDomain: true,
            type: 'POST',
            url: serviceUrl,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            data: Json.stringify({ 'grant_type':'password','userName':email, 'Password': pwd }),
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#value1').text(data);
        }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#value1').text(jqXHR.responseText || textStatus);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tested it, but it didn't work. When I've tested it on the server, I got a grant_type error. What I've noticed on the client via Chrome is that the request is sent via GET. I've changed the button click to make it a jQuery event and use event.preventDefault() but no luck.